# How to write Puppet modules for packages such as tigervnc or openvpn that require the user to set passwords or default settings?

Tags: automation, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am learning puppet and am trying to write modules to install services such as tigervnc and openvpn.

The problem is that for tigervnc requires the initial password setting by the user. I have tried using:
    "exec {'/usr/bin/echo password | /usr/bin/vncpasswd > ~/.vnc/passwd"
This works if I run it on the command line if I'm logged in as the user but does not work when run via puppet.

The problem with openvnc is that it requires a lot of user interaction for the default settings for certificate generation/certificate authority and key generation.
I have tried using execs with the "pkitool" methods which work to a point but not very well or stable. I am also wary of using many execs if there is a better way to do it.

So to sum up my main question is how to deal with these user interactions when trying to automate installations with puppet, and is there a better way than running lots of execs which to me seem like a last resort ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If setting up a piece of software requires user interaction, I don't really see a way around `exec`. Keeping its use to a minimum is indeed a sensible design goal.

An economic approach is to

1. create a script that does all the necessary lifting that Puppet resources cannot perform
2. make Puppet deploy that script to the agent
3. run it at appropriate times via `exec` (along with good `creates` or `onlyif` queries)

Scripts that run installation wizards that rely on interactive input should probably rely on `expect` and friends.